# Making a test double for a struct in a unit test using link-time substitution

Tags: c, unit-testing

I'm trying out unit test with the [CppUTest](http://www.cpputest.org/) framework. I'm using it on an existing code module and need to make doubles for many of the functions included by the module. Making doubles for functions works well, but I'm having problems with structs included into the module alongside the functions. How do I include test doubles for structs?

Comment: Stubs, code for isolating the code under test.

Comment: Why can't you use the existing structs as they are? If you must, use different objects, not different types: it's like you want to change all `int`s to `testint`s ...

Comment: The problem is that I can't (will not) change the code under test (CUT) (an excising module). The CUT includes a module the I want to stub out. This is done by like-time substitution, but the structs present in the module to be included are not available after linking because only the functions are substituted. How do I make the structs available without changing the CUT?

Comment: If you have a mock module that provides the substituted functions, can it also provide the replacement structs?

Comment: No, the mock functions are link-time substituted with the implementation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should use the real struct, unless you are faking a module that is built around an abstract data type.  Then you define the ADT struct in the double.

If you are really asking how do you test with global structures, you can create a defining instance of the struct in the test case or a test helper file.

If neither of these ideas fit your situation, please give some more details or an example.

James

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by including all the surrounding modules thereby also including the structs and then substitution the functions when linker.